# How to do php redirect from fork process

Tags: php

Is it possible to do an http direct when the child process of a fork has returned to the parent?

I tried doing:

```
header("Location: http://dev.mysite.com/invokefork.php?semaphoreid=".$semaphoreid."/");
```

This resulted in the error below, which is strange because there is nothing being echoed out when I'm running `fork.php` from the terminal.  This script is normally run by a call to `exec()` within `invokefork.php`

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

Obviously I can't do an http redirect from the command line, I just wanted to see what would happen.  When I tried running `invokefork.php` from the browser it didn't do the redirect.  The warning is present at the same line that the `header()` call is on.

What want to do is have a background process which takes params and performs a search.  While the search is being performed I'm thinking of redirecting to a "searching" page which checks the semaphore every 30 secs to see if it has been populated with data.

This should help understand a little more:

```
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); 
    if ($pid == -1) { 
       die("could not fork"); 
    } elseif ($pid) { 
        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WUNTRACED);

    } else { 
        // emulate db/web service query.  
        sleep(10);

        /*
            Do webservice / database query here
            When results return add them to shared memory
            Redirect and pass semaphore id to so the data
            from the semaphore can be looked up.
        */

       header("Location: http://dev.globalgatewaydemo.com/invokefork.php?pid=".$pid."/");

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't work in a CLI script anyway. But why/how/what are you forking a PHP process in the first place? That would severe the F/CGI pipe to the webserver for most SAPIs anyway. Explain that more exactly. -- As for the error: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957) - check warning details (file+line no) yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: @mario I've added some further detail, hope this makes a bit more sense :)